# Trying to implement `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` in Python3.6

Tags: windows, python-3.x, signals

I'm reading about signals and am attempting to implement `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT`

From what I"m understanding, if the user presses CTRC + C while the program is running, a signal will be sent to kill a program. I can specify the program as a parameter?

My attempt to test out the usage:

```
import sys
import signal
import time
import os


os.kill('python.exe', signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)

while(1):
    print ("Wait...")
    time.sleep(10)
```

However, it seems I need a pid number and 'python.exe' doesn't work. I looked under processes and I can't seem to find a PID number. I did see a PID column under services, but there were so many services -- I couldn't find a  python one.

So how do I find PID number?
Also, does signal_CTRL_C_EVENT always have to be used within os.kill?
Can It be used for other purposes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows doesn't implement Unix signals, so Python fakes `os.kill`. Unfortunately its implementation is confusing. It *should* have been split up into `os.kill` and `os.killpg`, but we're stuck with an implementation that mixes the two. To send Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break, you need to use `os.kill` as if it were really `os.killpg`.

When its `signal` argument is either `CTRL_C_EVENT` (0) or `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` (1), `os.kill` calls WinAPI `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`. This instructs the console (i.e. the conhost.exe instance that's hosting the console window of the current process) to send the event to a given process *group* ID (PGID). Group ID 0 is special cased to broadcast the event to all processes attached to the console. Otherwise 
a process group ID is the ID of the lead process in a process group. Every process is either created as the leader of a new group or inherits the group of its parent. A new group can be created via the `CreateProcess` creation flag `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`.

If either calling `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` fails (e.g. the current process isn't attached to a console) or the `signal` argument isn't one of the above-mentioned control events, then `os.kill` instead attempts to open a handle for the given process ID (PID) with terminate access and call WinAPI `TerminateProcess`. This function is like sending a `SIGKILL` signal in Unix, but with a variable exit code. Note the confusion in that it operates on an individual process (i.e. `kill`), not a process group (i.e. `killpg`).

Windows doesn't provide a function to get the group ID of a process, so generally the only way to get a valid PGID is to create the process yourself. You can pass the `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag to `subprocess.Popen` via its `creationflags` parameter. Then you can send Ctrl+Break to the child process and all of its children that are in the same group, but only if it's a console process that's attached to the same console as your current process, i.e. it won't work if you also also use any of these flags: `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`, or `DETACHED_PROCESS`. Also, Ctrl+C is disabled in such a process, unless the child manually enables it via WinAPI `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`.

Only use `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)` when you know for certain that your current process was started as the lead process of a group. Otherwise the behavior is undefined, and in practice it works like sending to process group ID 0.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had read another answer by you , where you explained the limitations of Windows signals (most of it had gone over my head)

Comment: @moondra, since Windows doesn't have Unix signals, it's definitely limited. The Windows C runtime emulates the 6 signals that standard C requires: `SIGILL` (illegal instruction), `SIGSEGV` (invalid memory access), and `SIGFPE` (floating point exception) are implemented via structured exception handling (SEH); `SIGABRT` (abort) and  `SIGTERM` (terminate) are implemented for use with `raise` within-process only (i.e. there's no `kill`); and `SIGINT` (interrupt) and non-standard `SIGBREAK` are implemented using a console control event handler for Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break.

Comment: CPython comes out of the Unix environment. It doesn't have built-in support for a lot of Windows programming concepts, such as structured and vectored exception handling, window messages and timers, kernel event and timer objects, or asynchronous procedure calls (APCs) using alertable waits.

Answer (score 1):

You can get pid via os.getpid()

```
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
```

Comment: Thanks. Going to play around with it.

Comment: It seems the os.kill is killing the program though, without even waiting for a signal. The script literally gets killed within a second of being called.

Comment: Using the current process ID is fine for sending it a `SIGINT` on Unix, but this is generally wrong on Windows. You can only send `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` to process groups, which works more like `killpg`. Sending to the current process ID will likely trigger the undefined behavior of sending the event to every process that's attached to the console, i.e. like sending to group ID 0.