# Code should kill the terminal before generating a loop because it found the value but it is only killing it after looping

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For this project I'm using `Visual Studio Code` on `Windows 11`

In this file example `StackOverflowTest.py`, if there are `5` values in the list, I want the terminal to be killed:

```
import os
import signal

def kill_terminal():
    os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)

def test_kill():
    list_test = [1,2,3,4,5]
    if (len(list_test) == 5):
        kill_terminal()

def main():
    print('Start Process')
    test_kill()
```

I created a loop to activate the `main()` function from the previous file, but in theory it was to kill the terminal on the first call that is made, but that doesn't happen, it only kills the terminal in the second looping:

```
from random import randint
import time
import schedule
import StackOverflowTest
import sys

StackOverflowTest.main()
def trigger():
    StackOverflowTest.main()
schedule.every(1).seconds.do(trigger)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    for remaining in range(randint(5,10), 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write('\r')
        sys.stdout.write('Next activation in {:2d} seconds'.format(remaining))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write('\r                               \n')
```

The correct way it should happen would be like this:
As it finds the value `5`, the correct thing was to kill the terminal after the first `Start Process`.

```
Start Process
~~~~KILL TERMINAL~~~~
```

However as it is not working correctly, it is happening like this:

```
Start Process
Next activation in 3 seconds
Next activation in 2 seconds
Next activation in 1 seconds
Start Process
~~~~KILL TERMINAL~~~~
```

As can be seen he kill the terminal only in the second time run `main()`.

How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: @BrondbyIF I don't have much experience with Windows but I think it is worth trying to change `SIGTERM` to `SIGKILL` to get the expected behavior

Comment: Hi @OlegAndriyanov Thanks for trying to help even though not very knowledgeable about Windows, but unfortunately there is no ```SIGKILL``` in the options. Anyway, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Have you tried changing `os.kill` to `os.system("taskkill /f /pid " + str(os.getppid())`? I can't try it now

Comment: How about calling `os.kill` twice in `kill_terminal()`?

Comment: @azelcer As the call comes from another code, the way you indicated doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @aaron It worked, but doesn't that make the code too weird and might not generate some sort of future conflict? Because I honestly didn't understand why once he didn't kill the terminal but twice he did.

Comment: SIGTERM gracefully kills the process, so it might not happen immediately or the process may choose to ignore it.

Comment: You can put ```time.sleep(1e-100)``` in place where you want to receive ```signal.SIGTERM```
In your case propably right after ```while 1:```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, `signal` has a [`CTRL_C_EVENT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.CTRL_C_EVENT) that can be sent to console processes that share a common console window. See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill).

So if you replace the `kill_terminal` function for the following:

```
def kill_terminal():
    os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
```

the terminal closes immediately.

I think the reason why `SIGTERM` doesn't work is that the Python interpreter process is a child of the `cmd.exe` process and therefore waits for it. `SIGKILL` is only available for Unix, so it seems that `CTRL_C_EVENT` does the job for Windows.

The implementation of signals for Windows is a bit confusing. Read more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147750/1388292).

[image: Possible explanation]